# Titles composed entirely of math symbols

Tags: ho.history-overview, soft-question, recreational-mathematics, big-list

I apologize for burdening MO with such a vapid, nonresearch question, but
I have been curious ever since
Suvrit's popular October 2010
[*Most memorable titles* MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44326/most-memorable-titles)
if there were any "$E=mc^2$-titles," as I think of them—how Einstein in retrospect might have entitled his 1905 paper
(instead of
"Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper"!)—paper/book titles composed entirely of math symbols.

There are two close misses in the responses to that MO question:
Connes et al.'s
["Fun with $\mathbb{F}_{1}$"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.2401),
and Taubes's
["${\rm GR}={\rm SW}$: Counting curves and connections."](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-52/issue-3/rm-GRrm-SW-counting-curves-and-connections/10.4310/jdg/1214425348.full)
The only title entirely composed of math symbols with which I'm familiar is the delightful book *[A=B](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html)*, by Marko Petkovsek, Herbert Wilf, and Doron Zeilberger.
Can you identify others?

Please interpret this question in a weekend-recreational spirit! :-)

Comment: If Chaitin came out with a book called $\Omega$, that would be the last word in "$E=mc^2$-titles (sorry, couldn't help myself).

Comment: On "Fun with $\mathbb{F}_1$" it's worth noticing that the French for "1" is "un".. :)

Comment: The "most memorable titles MO question" was only secondarily a request for examples of titles, but that secondary question was the only one that people answered, until after a large number of such answers had appeared.  I think I posted at least two such examples that were favorable viewed, but then I posted something that was closer to the primary thrust of the question.  I was severely and in fact abusively taken to task for not staying on topic, by someone who would have known that I was in fact on topic if he had read the question.

Comment: .....and the design of the software, and to some extent the culture, of MO, tacitly encourages such abuses.

Comment: Not sure if it counts, but if it does not exist why not create it? That's exactly I did with Pedia press of Wikipedia whose cover is posted here. http://s877.photobucket.com/albums/ab334/omega741/?action=view&current=Picture094.jpg

Comment: A few months ago, I ran across a preprint whose title consisted two simple _figures_ separated by an equals sign. Of course, now I've forgotten the authors.

Comment: Jeff: Cool! Let's collectively try to track it down...

Comment: P = NP (Well, it's not out yet, but if I ever prove it, that will be the title.)

Comment: After scrolling down this page I can say this is *also* a list of terrible titles (*except* for P=NP)

Comment: Very classical: $NUM=\Delta + \Delta + \Delta$ !!!

Answer (score 77):

$SL_2(\mathbf{R})$ ([link](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-0-387-96198-9))

Comment: @David: Great example!  "$SL_2(R)$ gives the student an introduction to the infinite dimensional representation theory of semisimple Lie groups by concentrating on one example--$SL_2(R)$." 

Answer (score 58):

**!**

(Title of a talk about the factorial function by Manjul Bhargava at the Clay conference in Paris in the year 2000.)

Comment: Along this line, Doron Zeilberger gave a talk [for an REU program about nothing](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimhtml/nothing.html), and his title was, well, nothing at all. (Not "nothing". But nothing.) Unfortunately, I am not sure if for this exercise of Joseph's, whether "consisting of mathematical symbols" requires the subset to be non-trivial. 

Answer (score 52):

[7 373 170 279 850](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2000%2D69%2D229/S0025%2D5718%2D99%2D01116%2D3/S0025%2D5718%2D99%2D01116%2D3.pdf)

Comment: Ha! Has their conjecture stood fast these past dozen years? (Abstract: "We conjecture that 7,373,170,279,850 is the largest integer which cannot be expressed as the sum of four nonnegative integral cubes.")

Comment: I think so. At the moment it is difficult for me to search literature. But in a similar spirit, it is known that 13792 is the largest number not expressible as a sum of 16 biquadrates; Deshouillers, Kawada, Wooley, Mém. Soc. Math. France 100, 2005.  

Comment: I guess "the largest number not expressible as" offers several opportunities...

Comment: Let me explain why this precise problems are considered: By a classical result of Hilbert (solving Waring's problem) every nonnegative integer is a sum of a fixed number of k-th nonnegative integral powers. (The fixed depends of course on the k).
One can now ask what is the best 'fixed' for a given k. It turns out that small numbers cause most problems and one gets by (for given k) with a smaller number of k-th powers, if one just wants all sufficiently large integers as a sum. Now, this raises the question, what is the 'sufficiently large'. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring's_problem

Comment: This gets my third vote.  Gerhard "Email Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.07.11 

Comment: @Joseph: I think so, see http://oeis.org/A022566 .

Answer (score 34):

[$H=W$](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=164252)

Comment: "Two concepts which are often used in the theory of partial differential equations and the calculus of variations are the so-called $H$ spaces and $W$ spaces."

Answer (score 32):

[$R(4,5)=25$](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/r45.pdf)

B. D. McKay and S. P. Radziszowski, J. Graph Theory, 19 (1995) 309-322.

The title is also the main theorem.  $R(4,5)$ is a classical Ramsey number (the one most recently determined exactly).

Comment: In the same vein, [$R(5,5) \le 48$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.08768) was posted yesterday.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69967/titles-composed-entirely-of-math-symbols#comment655834_83601), mentioned mere minutes earlier in an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/265757).

Answer (score 29):

Professor Luca and his co-authors are surely fond of this kind of titles:

- F. Luca & B. de Weger, $\sigma_k(F_m)=F_n$. New Zealand J. Math. 40 (2010), 1–13.
- F. Luca & F. Nicolae, $\phi(F_n)=F_m$. Integers 9 (2009), A30, 375–400.
- F. Luca & M. Mignotte, $\phi(F_{11})=88$. Divulg. Mat. 14 (2006), no. 2, 101–106.
- F. Luca & P. Stănică, $F_1F_2F_3F_4F_5F_6F_8F_{10}F_{12}=11!$. Port. Math. (N.S.) 63 (2006), no. 3, 251–260.

Answer (score 25):

Would [IP=PSPACE](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=146609&CFID=31867723&CFTOKEN=95840967) count?

Comment: Also QIP=PSPACE: https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4737

Answer (score 20):

McCarthy, Charles A. $c_p.$ Israel J. Math. 5 1967 249–271.

Comment: MathSciNet link: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0225140

Answer (score 17):

210=14*15=5*6*7

I may have the title wrong.  It is about the simultaneous solution of some Pell-like equations.  I will provide more detail as my memory permits.

Gerhard "Email Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.07.10

Comment: That's a nice one. I heard of this once, but completely forgot. Nice to be reminded.

Comment: Pinter and deWeger, "$210 = 14 \times 15 = 5 \times 6 \times 7 = \binom{21}{4} = \binom{10}{4}$". Publ. Math. Debrecen. 51(1-2) 175-189 (1997). "It is given all the solutions to the Diophantine equations $(y−1)y(y+1)=\binom{n}{4}$ and $x (x+1) = \binom{n}{4}$." 

Comment: From http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44326/ : http://deweger.xs4all.nl/papers/%5B22%5DPidW-210-PubMatDebr%5B1997%5D.pdf

Answer (score 17):

[$\Delta=b^2-4ac$](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=847347), by Jean-Pierre Serre (Math. Medley, Singapore Math. Soc. 13, 1985, 1-10).

Comment: J.-P. Serre also has a book entitled `$SL_2$'. No wait, come to
think of it the title also mentions `Arbres, amalgames', whatever
they are.

Comment: There *is* Lang's "SL$_2(\bf R)$",  which is the highest-voted answer to this question (by **David Roberts**).

Comment: @‍DavidRoberts's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/69969) [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69967/titles-composed-entirely-of-math-symbols#comment655861_83617) by @NoamD.Elkies.

Answer (score 17):

- Christopher J. Mulvey, *&*, Second topology conference (Taormina, 1984). Rend. Circ. Mat. Palermo (2) Suppl. No. 12 (1986) 99–104 ([MR0853151](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=853151))

Yes, this is the title. Just "&". :-)

From Mulvey's [homepage](http://www.maths.sussex.ac.uk/Staff/CJM/research/CJMResearch.htm): "This paper, presented at the Topology Meeting in Taormina, Sicily in April, 1984, introduced the concept of [quantale](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Quantale), outlining the programme of work in the spectral theory of C*-algebras and the constructive foundations of quantum mechanics to which it was expected to contribute. The paper is a slight development of that which appeared in the Tagungsbericht of the Category Meeting at Oberwolfach in September, 1983. It is included here since, although often quoted, it is more difficult to obtain in its published form in the Rendiconti del Circolo Matematico di Palermo. "

Answer (score 15):

$H_g^1(K,V)=H_{st}^1(K,V)$

An unpublished manuscript by Osamu Hyodo (who passed away untimely).

Answer (score 15):

This just in (https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.08768):

$$R(5,5) \leq 48$$

Answer (score 14):

$\int_x^{hx}(g^*\alpha-\alpha)$ (by Kedra and Gal)

http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0825

Answer (score 14):

[Here](http://www.nullplug.org/publications/e-vs-h-infinity.pdf) is $H_\infty\not= E_\infty$, wherein Justin Noel gives an example of an $H_\infty$-structure on a ring spectrum which does not descend from an $E_\infty$-structure.

Answer (score 12):

"Pi" (I keep "A source book" in parentheses to hide the non-mathematical part), L. B. Berggren, J. M. Borwein, P. B. Borwein (Eds.).

["Z=60"](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/events/Z60/), Conference in Honor of Doron Zeilberger's 60th Birthday (this, of course, is influenced by one of my favorite titles "[$A=B$](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/Downld.html)").

**Removed** (following the healthy criticism):
["2012"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_%28film%29), a 2009 American science fiction disaster movie.

Comment: +1 for Pi and Zeilberger. 

And, if works of fiction count, I think one should add 2001 (and 2010, 2061, 3001); let's ignore the odyssey add-ons.

Answer (score 12):

$$\left(1+\frac{d}{dz}\right)^{-1}$$

only a preprint, though: http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3045

EDIT: As of 3 Oct 2016 "This paper has been withdrawn due to an error in the proof of Claim I.3.5"

Answer (score 11):

$H_8$, by Jacques Martinet.

$GL_n$, by William Casselman.

Both these articles appear in the a book edited by Albrecht Fröhlich:
*Algebraic number fields: L-functions and Galois properties* (Proc. Sympos., Univ. Durham, Durham, 1975), pp. 525–538. Academic Press, London, 1977.

Answer (score 9):

Close but no cigar: *On $O_n$,* DE Evans
RIMS, Kyoto Univ 16 (1980) 915-927, and its sequel *On $_{+ 1}$,*
H Araki, AL Carey, DE Evans
J. Operator Theory 12 (2) (1984), 247-26.

$O_n$ (Oh, not zero) is the Cuntz C*-algebra. I thought this was a very clever title at the time.

Answer (score 9):

**MIP*=RE**

Zhengfeng Ji, Anand Natarajan, Thomas Vidick, John Wright, Henry Yuen.
[arXiv Abstract](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04383). 13 Jan 2020.

> ...a negative answer to Tsirelson's problem... our results provide a refutation of Connes' embedding conjecture...

Answer (score 8):

$K_1(A,B,I)$

S. Geller, C. Weibel, J. Reine Angew. Math. 342 (1983), 12–34.

$K(A,B,I)$: II

S. Geller, C. Weibel, K-Theory 2 (1989), no. 6, 753-760.

Answer (score 8):

Jacques Roubaud has a book named $\in$, published by Gallimard in Paris 1967. It's not listed on his English wiki page (and is a pain to google if, like me, you've forgotten his name).

Here is a picture of the cover from French Amazon:

[image: Picture of cover]

Answer (score 7):

$\Gamma_4=0$

is the subtitle of Jean Cerf's famous lecture notes: Sur les difféomorphismes de la sphère de dimension trois $(\Gamma _{4}=0)$. (French) 
Lecture Notes in Mathematics, No. 53 Springer-Verlag, Berlin-New York 1968 xii+133 pp.

Answer (score 7):

I apologize for a bit of vanity, which, worse yet, is not even a proper example: I nearly published a paper entitled [$T^0_2(MSP)=PV_1$](http://math.cas.cz/~jerabek/archive/t02.ps.gz), but a referee made me [rename it](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/malq.200610019) in the final version.

Comment: Ha!  I wonder how many other pithy paper titles were quashed by referees...

Comment: I wanted to publish a paper called "B-pairs and (φ,Γ)-modules" but the editors made me change it on the ground that they did not want too many math symbols in a title.

Comment: Michael Rosen and I wanted to publish, with title “Ordinary Abelian varieties and $u$ and $I$”, but that was quashed, @JosephO'Rourke .

Comment: @Lubin: $u$ & $I$: Ha!

Answer (score 7):

Thomas Forster's PhD thesis is called "[NF](http://www.dspace.cam.ac.uk/handle/1810/223940)". On his website he claims that this is the shortest title for a Cambrige maths PhD on record. The abstract is also pretty short.

Answer (score 7):

[$H^4(Co_0;\mathbf{Z})=\mathbf{Z}/24$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.07587)

Answer (score 6):

$K_{i}^{loc}(\mathbb{C})$, $i = 0, 1$, by Nicolae Teleman ([link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2421)).

Answer (score 5):

*Q* ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.08152))

Answer (score 5):

The monograph $Lx=b$ by Nisheeth Vishnoi ([here](http://www.nowpublishers.com/article/Details/TCS-054)), on fast ways to solve Laplacian systems.

Answer (score 5):

[$\mathcal{C}(A)$](http://repository.ubn.ru.nl/handle/2066/158429)

PhD thesis about posets of commutative C*-subalgebras. According to some P.R. agent at the Radboud University, it might be the shortest title for a Dutch PhD thesis, but I am not completely sure whether or not that is true.

Answer (score 5):

Not a paper, but Dan Freed's talk [4-3-2 8-7-6](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/tillmann/ASPECTSfreed.pdf) about topological and conformal field theories.

Comment: Neat.  Naturally if we allow talk titles then there's much bigger scope
for this kind of thing; I've given a few such talk titles myself,
including "$6561101970383!$" (see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19170 ).

Answer (score 3):

A new book just on the arXiv today:

- Garth Warner, $G$, $\Gamma$, $G/\Gamma$, [arXiv:2306.12433](https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.12433)

Answer (score 2):

I have just noticed that nobody has mentioned so far the paper

[714 and 715](https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/714and715.pdf)

by C. Nelson, D. E. Penney, and C. Pomerance.

This paper appeared in the second issue of vol. 7 (Spring, 1974) of the *Journal of Recreational Mathematics*; it is famous because it was precisely in its pages that the notion of [Ruth-Aaron pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruth%E2%80%93Aaron_pair) was first introduced.

Answer (score 2):

- Yann Bugeaud, $B'$, [arXiv:2209.00275](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.00275).